# jQuery ui timepicker add-on - range issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker, timepicker, add-on, daterangepicker

recently I'm using the jQuery timepicker add-on.
I follow the example to create a time picker
(in the following link, the 4th example)
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/#range_examples

I've create a date-range picker, like this

```
var startDateTextBox = $('#date_start');
var endDateTextBox = $('#date_end');

$.timepicker.dateRange(
    startDateTextBox,
    endDateTextBox,
    {
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        minInterval: 0, 
        maxInterval: 0, 
        start: {}, // start picker options
        end: {} // end picker options
    }
);
```

However, for the start date, it can current choose the date <= the end date.
I hope I can choose **"any date"** for the start date.
Like the example in this http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Can anyone teach me how to achieve this with this timepicker addon? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `.on('change',function(){ })` set the `minDate` and `maxDate` for start and end date. Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bmmskpb3/#&togetherjs=cpAt2Aqeg9)

JS:

```
var startDateTextBox = $('#date_start');
var endDateTextBox = $('#date_end');

$( function() {
    var dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd",
      from = startDateTextBox.datepicker({
          defaultDate: "+1w",
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths: 3,
          dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
        })
        .on( "change", function() {
          to.datepicker( "option", "minDate", getDate( this ) );
        }),
      to = endDateTextBox.datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'
      })
      .on( "change", function() {
        from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
      });


    function getDate( element ) {
      var date;
      try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
        alert(date);
      } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
      }
      return date;
    }
  });
```

HTML:

```
<input id="date_start"/>
<input id="date_end"/>
```

Comment: It seems that it can only implement separately. Thanks for your answer